# Angels of impurity before marriage?

Tags: tefilla, marriage, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity, malach-angel

I cam across an article here stating that before we marry, each person has an 'angel of impurity' attached to them from birth.
https://www.dailyhalacha.com/WeeklyParasha.asp?ParashaClipID=754

I understand that there is a general opinion that those who are unmarried (especially men) are often told to be extra stringent about temptation, but I've never heard it put this way before.

They also reference the Amidah, but seem to have replaced all Hebrew with question-marks, so that's no help.

Can anyone give me more information (ideally from a source in English or translated, please)?

Comment: This sounds weird ...

Comment: It's incorrect.

Comment: Probably a euphemism or mistranslation or nothing but a teaching mashal

Comment: Some Sefardic Siddurim have allusions to these impure forces in the Berachos of השיבה and ולמלשינים.

Comment: @IsraelReader Can you please clarify? I need it in English.